# What needs to be added to webea.config.ini EA Pro Cloud file to access database over browser?

Tags: enterprise-architect, enterprise-architecture

I have setup an EA pro cloud server and its successfully connected from the client side. The connection to the data base server is also established via client. Now i want to access the content of the database over the the cloud via browser and for that i have to make changes to webea.config on the cloud server. The webea.config has lots of properties, actually i have no idea what all to add against those fields for accessing the database over the browser. Following is the webea_config.ini:

```
    model1 = "Pro Cloud "
    model2 = "Pro Cloud2"


    [model1 : settings]
    sscs_protocol = "http"
    sscs_server = "localhost"
    sscs_port = "804"
    sscs_db_alias = "MY_SERVER"
    auth_code = ""
    login_prompt = "false"
    default_diagram = ""
    show_discuss = "false"
```

On the browser i see as :

[image]

But when i click on pro cloud it does not take me to the database contents.
Can anyone please explain me what all do i need to add webea_config.ini file So that i get to the contents inside the database.

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.sparxsystems.com/bin/webea.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

maybe localhost isn't known from outside, did you try providing a IP address?

Also i'd first test the same connection in 'Connect to Cloud' option in EA (from the machine where I'm trying to access from browser).

Also please ensure you have set the license and other settings required for PCS to work, refer to https://prolaborate.com/resources/documentation/installation-guide?articles=SetupProCloudServer to double check all configs are in place.